# How Can I Automatically Separate a Mesh into Individual Faces (meshes) in Blender?

Tags: scripting, faces, select

How do I separate a selected mesh into multiple meshes based on its faces.

What I know how to do: enter Edit mode, select a face of a cube, press <kbd>P</kbd> for separate, press <kbd>S</kbd> for selection, and repeat this 5 more times, so instead of one mesh, I have an object with 6 separated meshes.

But this is time consuming when the mesh is more complex, for example an Icosphere

[image].

I want to find a way, maybe you can reference a Python script, or short cut, to do this separation step on all the faces of the mesh, without selecting them one by one.

Is it possible?

Comment: Alt M (Split) > Faces by Edges then P (Separate) > By Loose Parts?

Comment: YES! thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> *(Split) > Faces by Edges* then <kbd>P</kbd> *(Separate) > By Loose Parts*